# How can I use lapply with my own function on a large list of data frames all with different number of rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have read in 25 .xlsx files using

```
mydata = lapply(filenames, read.xlsx, 1, sheetName = "Sheet1", startRow = 47, header = FALSE, row.names = NULL)
```

Each element in this long list of data frames has a different number of rows.
I then defined my own function which should add three new columns to each data frame based on the values in each data frame.

```
add.columns = function(df){
    transform(df, Tot.count = ave(df$X4, df$X1, FUN = sum))
    Tot.sum = sum(df$X4)
    df$Tot.sum = c(Tot.sum) 
    transform(df, percentage = 100 * df$Tot.count/Tot.sum)}
```

I then want to use lapply to run my function on each data frame.  I tried

```
transformed.data = lapply(mydata, FUN = add.columns(mydata))
```

Which is giving me an error because my data frames have different numbers of rows.

```
    Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 114, 121, 147, 124, 112, 122, 119, 129, 115, 116, 141, 87, 92, 73, 74, 120, 133, 125, 126, 138, 134
```

I have searched for a way to get this working but what I am finding applies to data frames of equal row length.  What do I need to do to get this to work with my data frames?

Comment: Try `lapply(mydata, function(x) add.columns(x))`

Comment: @RoyalTS  Thank you, that works.  I had to separate out part of my function but rewriting the call to the function the way you showed fixed the problem.

Comment: `lapply(mydata, add.columns)` should also work.